# Either issues with code, or issues with server with a angular.js routing issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to learn angular.js and incorporate some routes within my app.  The problem that i am running into is that i have hit a snag with creating routes.  I have two similar pages, and keep hitting 404's when i fire up the app in my local host.  I feel like i am close because everything is being read, and i have no errors within the console, but i still have yet to get the entire routes to properly operate.  I would be very grateful if anybody could take a quick look at my code below and see if there is anything that i need to alter to fix.

I believe that because of my circumstances i have one of two situations. I either have an issue with my code, or I have an issue with my server side routing.  If it is my code, i was hoping someone could see if there is any issues with it and help me out with it. If it is a problem with my server side routing, them I honestly have no idea what to do.

Below is my app.js file.  I feel like if there is anything that I have made a mistake with, it would be this one, but i'm not entirely sure.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(function ($routeProvider) { 
  $routeProvider 
    .when('/index/', { 
      controller: 'MainController', 
      templateUrl: 'views/home.html' 
    })
    .when('/test/', { 
      controller: 'testController', 
      templateUrl: 'views/home.html' 
    }) 
    .otherwise({ 
      redirectTo: '/' 
    }); 
});
```

These are the two html pages that i have within my views.  They very similar i just have different controllers associated with them.  The first one is called test, and the second one is called index

```
 <div class="main" ng-controller="testController">
        <div class="container">
        <h1>{{ title }}</h1>      
          <div ng-repeat="product in products" class="col-md-6">
            <product-info product="product"></product-info>
            </div>
          </div>          
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="main" ng-controller="MainController">
        <div class="container">
        <h1>{{ title }}</h1>      
          <div ng-repeat="product in products" class="col-md-6">
            <product-info product="product"></product-info>
            </div>
          </div>          
        </div>
    </div>
```

Finally, here is my general views index page:

```
<!doctype html>
 <html>
  <head>
<link href="css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="js/shared/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular-route.min.js"></script>"
  </head>
  <body ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="header">
      <div class="container">
        <h1>Stadiums in various leagues</h1>
      </div>
    </div>

     <div ng-view></div>

    <div class="footer">
      <div class="container">
    </div>

    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/MainController.js"></script>
    <script src="js/directives/productInfo.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: How did you setup your HTTP server? What URLs are you hitting? Also, you should remove the `ng-controller` attributes in your templates, the controller is already set by the `$routeProvider` service.

Comment: Are your URLs like `index.html#/index/` or `#/test/` ?  Also, your `otherwise` route points to `'/'`, though you don't have a route defined there (your default route is `'/index/'`

Comment: @Tom Initially my URL was /#/. I then changed my otherwise '/' to '/index/' and then it became #/index/. If i try to manually change the URL to just localhost:3000/index/ i wind up getting the 404.

Comment: @Iso I am using Node.js. I have a poor version of linux and wound up having troubles from the start downloading node.js, so i wound up following this tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-run-a-node-js-app-on-centos-6-4-64bit

I do really want to thank both of you for your help. I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: It would have to be localhost:3000/index.html/#index/ -- everything stems from the root index.html